# Cannot Recover Monero Wallet with Trezor

Tags: wallet-recovery

I’m trying to recover a Monero GUI wallet on a new MacBook Pro. (My old MacBook crashed and can no longer access it.) The Monero wallet was created with a Trezor T and I have a 12 word Monero seed phrase. However, when I download the Monero GUI on my new MacBook and attempt to restore it, it is asking for a 25 word seed phrase. How do I go about recovering my Monero wallet with a Trezor?

Comment: Please see the question linked. Essentially, you need to restore your mnemonic seed in a new Trezor device first. Thereafter, you can recover your Trezor Monero wallet in the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to use restore height 1692975 and that worked. Here's the steps: https://wiki.trezor.io/Monero_(XMR)